# Android: moving ball through touch

Tags: java, android

I am making a simple game for class on an Android phone in which you can change a ball's position by touch.  I had it working in Processing by simply using mouse position.  In Android, I am using the gesture scanner and corresponding methods for various gestures, but I can't figure out the exact way to pull in the coordinates of the touch method into the ball object's x/y coordinates.  I hope that I am making sense!  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

If your ball is an image in an `ImageView`, then you know the starting position of this ImageView object; save it in `prevPosition` variable. Whenever you encounter a touch event you will get the coordinates of the location where touch has taken place(`currPosition`), move your ball from prev location(`prevPosition`) to this new location and update your `prevPosition` variable(`prevPosition=currPosition`).

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

go with this code it is now included in your new sdk check it here.., thanks,
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/RenderScript/index.html;